# lockscreen : start activity when screen turns on

Tags: android, lockscreen

I m creating a simple lock having a simple logic i.e if user enters "1234" the lock will unlock and show the homescreen else show a error toast message.

```
  lock.java 
  -----
 public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    EditText edit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);      
     int a = 1234;

    if(edit==a)  // any logic here
    { 
      finish(); //user has typed correct now...pause the app until screen goes off
    }
   else
    {
      toast message here
      }
}}
```

I want this activity to start when user's screen gets timeout or screen is off.

I have searched many answers about broadcast receivers, service ,powermanager etc but as people just post half answers i.e what to add in main activity,what permission to add,how to block home button etc. and are very confusing .

i just want to know

1 - what to add in manifest ..permission, activity ,service etc.
2- how to use broadcast receiver to detect screen state.
3 - how to use service to start this activity.
4- how to handle homebutton,backbutton, handle call etc. and where to declare such methods.

i have spent much time in surfing other stack links but they are much confusing.
Answering this in proper step will help every user who want to make custom lock screen and handle on/off screen events.

Thanks